# Comparing two audio (Phone operator messages)

Tags: fft, audio-processing, pattern

I have this two wavs. Same audible audio differente data.

The audios are phone operator messages, so they are always the same.

[image]
Wav:http://instaud.io/3Ezu

[image]
Wav:http://instaud.io/3Ezw

Using this formula I found here i get how similar they are:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847570/use-convolution-to-find-a-reference-audio-sample-in-a-continuous-stream-of-sound

```
    double[] Data1 = GetMyWav1InDoubles();
    double[] Data2 = GetMyWav2InDoubles();
    double Mx = Data1.Average();
    double My = Data2.Average();

    double Denominator1 = Math.Sqrt(Data1.Sum(x => (x - Mx) * (x - Mx)));
    double Denominator2 = Math.Sqrt(Data2.Sum(y => (y - My) * (y - My)));
    double MaximumNormalizedCrossCorrelation = maxValue / (Denominator1 * Denominator2);
```

The MaximumNormalizedCrossCorrelation value es 56% similar which is low, considering they sound the same...

I have read I must do FFT and then compare! but I'm lost, I'm using:

http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.csharp.html#example_fft_real_d1

After getting the real part of the result I got this graphs

[image]
[image]

So, how can i get a similarity percentage?

I read this:
[image]
src: https://lstsal.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/comparing-two-audio-files/

**but how?**

Comment: no, the cross-correlation should give you a good result.  there is a method of computing cross-correlation using the FFT that should save you instruction cycles.  i am surprized it is as low as 0.56.  are you sure that the durations are the same?  could it be possible that one was *"stretched"* a little in time relative to the other?

Comment: where is `maxValue` defined in your code?  and `x` and `y`?

Comment: maxvalue is the highest double in both series, and x and y is the variable of the lambda! thats c# code.  (x=> x * 1) x is the value of the item inside de array

Comment: where/how is your cross-correlation computed?

Comment: http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.csharp.html#sub_corrr1d

Comment: I input the wav and the pattern to find and it return the cross! then i find the maxvalue like the link i shared in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847570/use-convolution-to-find-a-reference-audio-sample-in-a-continuous-stream-of-sound

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847570/use-convolution-to-find-a-reference-audio-sample-in-a-continuous-stream-of-sound

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93417/discussion-between-fraga-and-robert-bristow-johnson).